# When the tensor (monoidal) product of subcategories in a monoidal category is a full subcategory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Assume $(\mathsf{C}, I_{\mathsf{C}}, \otimes_{\mathsf{C}})$ is a monoidal category and let $\mathsf{D}, \mathsf{D}^{\prime} \subset \mathsf{C}$ denote two (full) subcategories. If I understand correctly, one can form a new subcategory $\mathsf{D} \otimes_{\mathsf{C}} \mathsf{D}^{\prime}$, where objects are $A \otimes_{\mathsf{C}}B$, for $A \in \textit{ob}(\mathsf{D})$, $B \in \textit{ob}(\mathsf{D}^{\prime})$ and morphisms $f \otimes_{\mathsf{C}}g: A \otimes_{\mathsf{C}}B \to A^{\prime} \otimes_{\mathsf{C}} B^{\prime}$, for $f \in \textit{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(A,B), g \in \textit{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(A^{\prime},B^{\prime})$. This new subcategory $\mathsf{D} \otimes_{\mathsf{C}} \mathsf{D}^{\prime}$ is not necessarily full subcategory of $\mathsf{C}$.

I was wondering under what assumption(s) is $\mathsf{D} \otimes_{\mathsf{C}} \mathsf{D}^{\prime}$ becoming a full subcategory. Equivalently, when morphisms between tensor products of objects come from the tensor product of their corresponding morphisms.

Comment: In the usual examples it is not a full subcategory.